# Haml and JavaScript and Ruby communication

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have some code, like this:

```
  %div{:id=>"alerts_tab",:class=>"settings_tab"}
    %div{:class=>"main_block"}
      %div{:class=>"left_block"}
        %p Select 1
        = radio_button_tag 'gender', 'male', :id=>"daily_frequency"
        Daily
        = radio_button_tag 'gender', 'male', :id=>"weekly_frequency"
        Weekly
        = radio_button_tag 'gender', 'male', :id=>"monthly_frequency"
        Monthly
        %p Try it
        %input{:name => "malfunction_affects_more", :type => "checkbox", :class => "check_box", :value=>"off"}
        AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
        %select{:class=>"custom_drop_down"}
          %option 1% users 'test'
```

I trying use JS for select data and move findings to ruby code. But I have some problems:
1. If I write JS code

```
:javascript
  $( "#save_settings" ).click(function() {
    var value = document.getElementById('daily_frequency');
    alert(value);
  });
```

It is not working, why?

2. If I catch all data how to move findings to ruby code. I don't know.

Please, help me with this problems.

Comment: well for starters I do not see a `DOM` Object with an `id` of `save_settings`?

Comment: **save_settings** it is id for my button and is working. My question about other. Why **var value = document.getElementById('daily_frequency');** not working?

Comment: working, sorry :)  document.getElementById('daily_frequency').checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong syntax. Check [this](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/radio_button_tag) out

The 3rd parameter sets the `checked` attribute, so this should work:

```
= radio_button_tag 'gender', 'male', false, :id=>"daily_frequency"
```

Side note for useful `haml` syntax:

```
%div{:id=>"alerts_tab",:class=>"settings_tab"}
```

can be written simply as

```
#alerts_tab.settings_tab
```

Comment: if I use next code: **document.getElementById('none_frequency').value** always I get only **male** but not **gender**. Why?

Comment: That's because 'male' is a value and 'gender' is a name

Comment: ok. how to get if checkbox control enable I get **true** other **false**?

Comment: I dont understand. 3rd parameter - true or false - sets if the radio button will be checked by default. (already clicked in)

Answer (score -1):

Your syntax is wrong: it should be

```
var value = document.getElementById('daily_frequency').value;
```

however, since you're using jQuery, you might as well use jQuery's syntax, which is neater:

```
var value = $("#daily_frequency").val();
```